# Javascript function is not getting called , form onclick=> funciton name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-3, checkbox

My check_uncheck function is called only when i open the inspect console.

As in my code when the user try to check the checkbox, then it should call the **check_uncheck** function, but this function get executed only if i open the inspect console , on that case only it get executed

When i didn't open my console logs by(inspect) on that case my method is not getting executed

This is my code

````
  ```
<%= form.check_box 'active',:onclick => "check_uncheck(this);" :class => "icheck", :"data-checkbox" => "icheckbox_square-blue" %>

<%= form.label 'active', 'library_books' %>
```

function check_unchek(element)
   {
     $("#save_it").attr("disabled", true);
   }
````

im not sure why it was like this
can any one help me out please

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the calculations ? If you want to check if the checkbox is check or not, you can use jQuery / JS manipulation DOM. More detail you can read from this [link](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/javascript/how-to-test-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-with-jquery.html).

After you can get the value of the checkbox, you can send the value to make a calculation in backend with AJAX and get the respond back.

Answer (score 0):

Well you'll need your Javascript/jQuery to be able to do this. But a checkbox only returns a checked/not checked value. So if the value you hope to get is in another element (most likely), you'll need some more manipulation to get this

Since you have a class attached to your checkbox, with jQuery you can :

```
let checked; 
 $('selector').change(function (e) {
        // checked will equal true if checked or false otherwise
        checked = $(this).is(':checked')); 
});
if(checked //Should return true if checked){
     let valReturned = $('selector-of-element-with-value)
     
     //You can now go ahead and perform calculations with values. 
 }
```